# Incorrect Access-Control-Allow-Origin being added automatically to POST & DELETE endpoints

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

I have an app built with FastAPI hosted on `API Gateway` using `serverless`.

The API: `https://xxxxx.execute-api.xx-xxxxxx-x.amazonaws.com/dev/{proxy+}`

Since most of my endpoints are proxy endpoints, I am adding to the [response headers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/) as follows:

```
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token"
```

I have 3 different types of endpoints: GET, POST & DELETE.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is correctly assigned in the GET request as follows:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true 
access-control-allow-headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,x-access-token 
access-control-allow-origin: * 
content-length: 150 
content-type: application/json 
date: Mon,09 Aug 2021 07:06:45 GMT 
x-amz-apigw-id: DyYQPFBHFiAFrQA= 
x-amzn-remapped-content-length: 150 
x-amzn-requestid: 24fac4dc-189c-468e-9ca7-1bfd6ccfbabe 
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-6110d401-2816fc3630142ecd24604935;Sampled=0
```

it is not correctly being assigned in the POST & DELETE methods. When I host it on API Gateway, the above-mentioned API is being automatically added to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in place of `"*"`, which I am specifically mentioning when I declare the response headers as shown above.

The response headers for the POST & DELETE methods:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true 
access-control-allow-headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,x-access-token  access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST,DELETE 
access-control-allow-origin: https://xxxxx.execute-api.xx-xxxxxx-x.amazonaws.com/dev/{proxy+} 
content-length: 392 
content-type: application/json 
date: Mon,09 Aug 2021 07:01:37 GMT 
x-amz-apigw-id: DyXgoHozliAFnJA= 
x-amzn-remapped-content-length: 392 
x-amzn-requestid: a03fad7e-1caf-4a8c-b188-932923085755 
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-6110d2d0-39fe47e07531d93a585117d7;Sampled=0
```

Because of this, the following error is shown in the frontend:

> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed
> by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there something that I am missing that should be added for these methods?

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

I'm setting the response headers to all the endpoints as follows:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/dimensioning",
    tags=["dimensioning"],
)

@router.post('/')
def post_body(response: Response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token"
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    # do the other stuff

@router.get('/')
def get_body(response: Response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token"
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    # do the other stuff

@router.delete('/')
def delete_body(response: Response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token"
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    # do the other stuff
```

I am also following the structure [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app). So in my `main.py`, as done [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/main.py), I have

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

**Edit 2**

When I inspect the response, I see that there are 2 APIs:

[image]

This is for the POST (which doesn't have the response headers I mention)
[image]

This is for the OPTIONS method
[image]

Comment: How are you setting the headers? You have to include more of your actual code to provide proper context. Are you handling GET/PUT/POST in different views? What is the relevant code in those views? How are you setting the headers you've given as an example?

Comment: @MatsLindh Hey, I have edited the question and added some more stuff

Comment: Since your app is a proxy endpoint, do you return the response from the other service or do you modify/elaborate it before returning it?

Comment: @Isabi Sorry, I didn't get your question

Comment: How do you create the actual response before returning it? You say your endpoints are proxy endpoints; do you proxy the headers from the backend service as well? What do you do with the `response` object through your method? (and you shouldn't need both the middleware and manual adding of CORS headers - as long as you add your middleware, that should be enough)

Comment: @MatsLindh I just added the response.headers to the endpoints and that's it. That's what it says in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/). The return of all the endpoints is a dict like `{'areas': [{some infos here}]}`. If I don't add the CORS headers manually, none of the end points work. After adding them, the GET works but POST & DELETE still cause a problem. I also tried using the [JSONresponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/), but that too doesn't work

Comment: For all the endpoints I have the reponse.headers added as mentioned in the question, but it works for GET and not for the other two.

Comment: Have you implemented support for the `OPTIONS` method? I.e. is it the OPTIONS request that fails (which is made for any non-simple requests) and not the actual POST/PUT? How are you wrapping FastAPI with api-gateway? Does it work as expected if you run it locally?

Comment: It works as expected locally. Locally I get: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. I am using [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide) for wrapping the Fastapi and hosting it directly on AWS as a API gateway + lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours on this issue and coordinating with the frontend developer, we realized that there was a missing parameter in the frontend that was required for the backend. It was causing an internal server error, that's why the headers were not available.

After adding the parameter, the requests were successful.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably related to the CORS specification.

According to the [CORS specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflight_requests_and_credentials) you're not allowed to combine `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` as it states:

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard.

CORS is highly dependent though on the implementation by the client and in this case also the API manager and there are differences between how `GET` requests are handled and how `POST` and other requests are handled. If you want to support localhost for development, you might have to explicitly set the correct value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your code or using the API gateway configuration.

Comment: Hey, I tried this too, but it's still not working :/

Comment: Usually, if the network tab says "CORS Error" there is more information in the browser console, can you post what error message you are getting there?

Comment: The problem is that in the GET the response headers are being added correctly, but in the POST, the headers are being added just to the OPTIONS and not to the POST. In the console the error: `Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v1/dimensioning/calc' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` and I added the localhost to origins

Comment: Do you specify the OPTIONS request yourself or do you use the API GW cors settings for this? Because the documentation states `If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway ignores CORS headers returned from your backend integration.` so there might be a problem there.

Comment: I just solved the problem. There was a missing parameter in the frontend that was required for the backend. It was causing an internal server error, that's why the headers were not available